# asp.net mvc 3 flash uploader ignores cookie (alternative?)

Tags: flash, asp.net-mvc-3, cookies, uploader

I use a flash uploader in a site that I created. I need to upload large files to the server. The problem is that this uploader uses flash. When it submits the data the cookies are not send back to the server so therefor I can't verify the user and this will fail. Is there anyway to force send the cookies back to the server? And if this is not possible, is there an other way to upload the data with an other component that sends back the cookies.

Answer (score 0):

There are several sites where this problem is discussed. The solution is, to manually pass the authorization information back to MVC using another post variable in flash. An implementation I've found is the `TokenizedAuthorizeAttribute`.

```
/// <summary>
/// A custom version of the <see cref="AuthorizeAttribute"/> that supports working
/// around a cookie/session bug in Flash.  
/// </summary>
/// <remarks>
/// Details of the bug and workaround can be found on this blog:
/// http://geekswithblogs.net/apopovsky/archive/2009/05/06/working-around-flash-cookie-bug-in-asp.net-mvc.aspx
/// </remarks>
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, Inherited = true, AllowMultiple = true)]
public class TokenizedAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The key to the authentication token that should be submitted somewhere in the request.
    /// </summary>
    private const string TOKEN_KEY = "AuthenticationToken";

    /// <summary>
    /// This changes the behavior of AuthorizeCore so that it will only authorize
    /// users if a valid token is submitted with the request.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="httpContext"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(System.Web.HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        string token = httpContext.Request.Params[TOKEN_KEY];

        if (token != null)
        {
            FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(token);

            if (ticket != null)
            {
                FormsIdentity identity = new FormsIdentity(ticket);
                string[] roles = System.Web.Security.Roles.GetRolesForUser(identity.Name);
                GenericPrincipal principal = new GenericPrincipal(identity, roles);
                httpContext.User = principal;
            }
        }

        return base.AuthorizeCore(httpContext);
    }
}
```

Following the [Link](http://geekswithblogs.net/apopovsky/archive/2009/05/06/working-around-flash-cookie-bug-in-asp.net-mvc.aspx) in the comment will help you further.

Comment: would work if there was not an external security meganism that is checking every result.

Comment: I use a identity server that checks everyrequest for a specific cookie. If that cookie is not there it will terminate the connection.